# Array structure with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm facing a array structure problem here.

Why this array

```
$plans = array(
    'id'   => 'free', 
    'name' => 'Free', 
    'sums' => array(
        'usd' => 0,
    ),
    'id'   => 'trial', 
    'name' => 'Trial', 
    'sums' => array(
        'usd' => 0,
    ),
);
```

returns me only this (last result of my array):

```
Array
(
    [id] => trial
    [name] => Trial
    [sums] => Array
        (
            [usd] => 0
        )

)
```

Any help with this will be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't use the same key more than once in an associative array. You need to use an array of arrays.

Comment: same keys overwrites with latest value

Answer (score 7):

That is because you overwrite the array keys in each array item effectively removing the value before it. You need an array of arrays for this data:

```
$plans = array(
    array(
        'id'   => 'free', 
        'name' => 'Free', 
        'sums' => array(
            'usd' => 0,
        )
    ),
    array(
        'id'   => 'trial', 
        'name' => 'Trial', 
        'sums' => array(
            'usd' => 0,
        )
    )
);
```